# Bounty minimum on other users' questions

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When we offer bounties on our own questions, we are given the options of 50-500 reputation in increments of 50. When offering bounties on questions posted by other users, the increment is the same, but starts at 100 instead of 50. Why is that?

**Note:** The [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) states (emphasis from FAQ):

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to *any* question as a bounty.

**EDIT (Feature Request):**
Can we get a note added to indicate that this is the case when starting a bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change applies only to questions you've answered, and was [made recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack) to dissuade users from attempting to gain reputation by manipulating the bounty system (the ethics of doing this are debatable, but that's neither here not there).